# mariadb, add 4th galera node failed

Tags: mysql, mariadb, cluster-computing, database-replication, galera

I have three `node` setup and running perfectly for the past months.
Recently I want to add another `node` in a different location but somehow I keep on getting errors.

At first, I was just following this tutorial (where I setup the first time few months ago) https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-and-configure-galera-cluster-on-ubuntu-1604/  I did not start all the nodes again from the beginning, I just has to find the file of `/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf`  in the other three `nodes` I added the new `nodes` ip into the previous three.  So for the forth one I had the `/etc/mysql/conf.d/galera.cnf` setup like...

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
bind-address=0.0.0.0
# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="galera_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://node1_ip,node2_ip,node3_ip,node4_ip"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="xx.xx.xxx.xxx"
wsrep_node_name="Node4"
```

somehow I am getting this HUGE error,

```
        Group state: e3ade7e7-e682-11e7-8d16-be7d28cda90e:36273
         Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
  [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: e3ade7e7-e682-11e7-8d16-be7d28cda90e:36273, view# 122: Primary, number of nodes: 4, my
  [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
  [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address 'xxx.node.4.ip' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'   --parent '22828'  ''
 rsyncd version 3.1.1 starting, listening on port 4444
  [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: rsync|xxx.node.4.ip:4444/rsync_sst
  [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
  [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 7 (3, 2)
  [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 36273, protocol version: 3
  [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
  [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not
          at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.
  [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (Node4) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 1.0 (Node1)(SYNCED) as donor.
  [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 36273)
  [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 1
  [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0 -> e3ade7e7-e682-11e7-8d16-be7d28cda90e:36273
 [Note] WSREP: (7642cf37, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 7642cf37 with addr tcp://xxx.node.4.ip:4567 timed out, no messages
 [Note] WSREP: (7642cf37, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
 mariadb.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
 Terminated
 WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup. rsync PID: 22875 
 sent 0 bytes  received 0 bytes  total size 0
 WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup done. 
  [ERROR] WSREP: Process was aborted.
  [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address 'xxx.node.4.ip' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/'
  [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read uuid:seqno and wsrep_gtid_domain_id from joiner script.
  [ERROR] WSREP: SST failed: 2 (No such file or directory)
  [ERROR] Aborting
 Error in my_thread_global_end(): 1 threads didn't exit
 mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 Failed to start MariaDB 10.1.33 database server.
```

P.S for the older 3 nodes maria db version is 10.1.29 and the new node is 10.1.33

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the ping time between the nodes?

Comment: @RickJames how can I check the ping between the nodes? Anyways, the 4th node would not start properly so I would personally think even the ping can't reach?

Comment: Are they geographically dispersed?  Can you go to a command line and do ping / tracert / traceroute to the host name or IP address?  Are the server ids distinct?